# после создания exe файла через pyinstaller при открытии exe выскакивает ошибка, с чем может быть связано?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, eel

[image: ошибка при открытии exe файла проекта]

библиотеки, используемые в проекте:

```
import json, pyaudio, datetime, time, pyowm, re
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
from translate import Translator
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard as k
from ahk import AHK
import pytesseract, cv2, subprocess, eel
from threading import Thread
from models.yandex_speak import ya_sp
from models.conv import conv
from models.record import rec
from models.yandex_text import sp_t
from models import pars
```

После ошибки программа не запускается.

В консоли до создания exe работает исправно.

Comment: Вы когда создавали файл, какие флаги использовали?

Comment: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "C:/1/Python/voice_helper/web;web/" --add-data "C:/1/Python/voice_helper/png;png/" --add-data "C:/1/Python/voice_helper/models;models/" --add-data "C:/1/Python/voice_helper/model_ru_small;model_ru_small/" --add-data "C:/1/Python/voice_helper/model_en_small;model_en_small/" --add-data "C:/1/Python/voice_helper/audio;audio/"  "C:/1/Python/voice_helper/voice_helper_eel.py"